# What is StatusMax?

Tags: final-fantasy-7

...apparently it's something appearing only in JPC version of the game, and it is frequently used to trigger some glitches circumventing locations in speedruns. There's an UI window which while open prevents some events. That's how the feature is abused to trigger glitches. But I can't find a word about the feature itself. What does it do? What does it change about the game? Any specific reasons why only JP version got it?

Comment: Have you asked XeroKynos (aka NEroNeRoNerON), who has the WR for JPC using StatusMAX glitch? He streams on Twitch pretty regularly and usually answers most every question posted.